# Whitenoise doesn't seem to help images to show up in heroku

Tags: django, heroku, whitenoise

I got the 404 error to images.

```
https://example.herokuapp.com/images/IMG_2060.JPG 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my tree of directory.

```
directory1
    |
    |-- manage.py
    |
    |-- build/
    |     |
    |     |--static/
    |     .
    |     .
    |
    |-- static/
    .     |
    .     |--images/
    .     .
    .     .
```

The images that I want to see are in directory1/static/images/.

### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
     ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ....
]


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

whitenoise version is 5.2.0. I deployed this app to Heroku. Everything works fine except images. Did I miss something?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's static file handling can be a bit confusing.

[STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) is supposed to be an empty directory which Django copies your static files *to* ready for serving. This is done by the `collectstatic` command which is run automatically by Heroku.

Directories you want it to copy files *from* should be listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

So if you change your settings like this it should work:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```